# Calculating Euclidean Distance

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I have the code below to calculate Euclidean Distance. however, my function does basically nothing. It gives no output and not even an error, it just runs and finishes.

```
lst_a=[1,2,3,4,5]
lst_b=[1,2,4,5,8]

def distance(lst_a, lst_b):
    sum_of = 0
    for x, y in zip(lst_a, lst_b):
        ans = (x - y)**2
        sum_of += ans
    return (sum_of)**(1/2)
```

Comment: Did you call the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you called the function?

```
distance(lst_a, lst_b)
```

Output:

```
3.3166247903554
```

For longer lists, you can also do this faster by summing a generator expression instead:

```
def distance(lst_a, lst_b):
    return sum((x-y)**2 for x, y in zip(lst_a, lst_b))**0.5
```

Or you could use `math.dist` (as pointed out in comments) which is significantly faster still:

```
import math
def distance(lst_a, lst_b):
    return math.dist(lst_a, lst_b)
```

Comment: The answer is no, since I am very new to python, I tend to make such simple mistakes!

Comment: How much faster is the generator version?

Comment: @KellyBundy ok for the given input it's slower but for longer lists it is a few % faster. actually I think it depends on python version previously on 3.8, on 3.10 they're the same

Comment: How fast is `math.dist` in comparison?

Comment: @KellyBundy it is an order of magnitude faster

Comment: Ok, that all agrees with my own benchmarks. The "Roughly equivalent to" code in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.dist) is btw also significantly faster, apparently squaring by 2.0 is faster (though could lose precision if the sum gets big).

Comment: And storing each difference in a variable and multiplying it with itself instead of squaring is even faster (but still far slower than `math.dist`).